# How can I get the specific user information from the list of users upon click in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-manipulation

I am writing a firebase mini chat web app where an admin can be able to privately chat with all the authenticated users.

so I used the firebase cloud-function to fetch the list of all users, code:

```js
//LISTING USERS FOR ADMIN
exports.listUsers = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  // check if user is admin (true "admin" custom claim), return error if not
  const isAdmin = context.auth.token.admin === true
  if (!isAdmin) {
    return {
      error: `Unauthorized.`
    }
  }

  return admin.auth().listUsers().then((listUsersResult) => {
      // go through users array, and deconstruct user objects down to required fields
      const result = listUsersResult.users.map((user) => {
        const {
          uid,
          email,
          photoURL,
          displayName,
          disabled
        } = user
        return {
          uid,
          email,
          photoURL,
          displayName,
          disabled
        }
      })

      return {
        result
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      return {
        error: 'Error listing users'
      }
    })
})
```

And from the front-end I called the cloud-function and displayed users using map method.

```js
const listUsers = functions.httpsCallable('listUsers');
listUsers().then(res => {
  const result = res.data.result;

  const output = result.map(item => {
    return `<div class="user">
              <img src="${item.photoURL}" /> 
              <p class="username">${item.displayName}</p>
            </div>`
  });

  listChats.innerHTML = output.join('');
})
```

Users are listed successfully. My problem now is if admin click on a specific user, I can be able to get or grab that specific user information like, id, displayName, etc.

thanks as you help me out

Comment: What about the onclick event on `<div class="user" onclick="showInformation(${item.id})>`? Then you pass the id of the user so you can get all information about him/her and display wherever you want.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to reply, I did exactly what you said but when I console log it out the id was printed out but with error message saying is not defined. eg: ``` djdfyfk27Ysjdja is not defined ``` and it’s the user’s id that was printed out. Thanks

Comment: Here is a naive example: https://jsbin.com/lenogor/2/edit?html,js,console,output.

Comment: thanks but that doesn't clarify my question. @MoshFeu

Comment: It demonstrate how to show an item details on click..

Comment: sorry but I think you demonstrate it in an advanced way, can you please make it beginner-friendly or add some comments in the codes? thanks... @MoshFeu

Comment: Sorry. It was the wrong link. Basically `listUsers` is just a fake response from the server. For each item in the list I create a new `div` (`createElement`), set its html the same you did, and append it to the list html element. Finally, I attach a `click` event to the element and alert the item details. Those are native js features: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener etc.

Comment: If there is something specific you don't understand, let me know. The fixed link is https://jsbin.com/lenogor/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Maaaaaaaaaann thank YOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU so much you have really solved my problem   can you please post the solution as an answer so that others can benefit and upvote... and please your social media handle, I just wanna follow you

Comment: Just did. I'm glad I could help.. You can have my social links from [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/863110/mosh-feu?tab=profile).

Comment: I have already followed you on Twitter and GitHub as well... Just a little reminder, in your answer you have given here ```listChats``` was mentioned twice and the last one I think maybe is a typo. thanks once again MAN!!

Comment: Despite the right and better solution @moshfeu gave, about my answer was missing just the `\'` otherwise the js will think this is a js variable and not a string, [here](https://codepen.io/drocha87/pen/oNLLBem) you can see it in action, but keep with @moshfeu answer.

Comment: yes I have gone through your answer and it works as well, thank you so much for giving me the idea and experience, I really appreciate it.!! @drocha87

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind a `click` event only on a DOM element. There are some ways to do this even if you added the element with `innerHTML`. But for simplicity, I'd offer you to not add the elements with `innerHTML` but with [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) which returns the DOM element.

So the logic is:

1. For each item, create a `div` element - `document.createElement('div')`
2. Set its html similar to what you did - `div.innerHTML`
3. Bind it a click event - `div.addEventListener('click', ..)`

This way, you have the item itself in the `addEventListener` callback's scope. That's why the `alert` works.

```js
function listUsers() {
  return Promise.resolve({
    data: {
      result: [
        {
          photoURL: 'https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png',
          displayName: 'john'
        }
      ]
    }
  })
}

listUsers().then(res => {
  const result = res.data.result;

  result.forEach(item => {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.classList.add('user');
    div.innerHTML = `
      <img src="${item.photoURL}" /> 
      <p class="username">${item.displayName}</p>
    `;
    div.addEventListener('click', () => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(item, null, 2));
    });
    listChats.appendChild(div);
  });

  listChats.innerHTML =  output.join('');
})
```

```html
<div id="listChats"></div>
```